# Task.WhenAny Can this be resolved from a Synchronous Pipeline?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I've been reviewing [How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c)  in order to get an async call to be resolved in a non-async function.

I am able to get my individual async tasks to resolve in the using Solution A of that article.  But i don't see how it can be done when the single async function itself contains a call to an array of async calls.  Right now it just freezes on the call

`var result = task.WaitAndUnwrapException();`

here is what i have

```
public static async Task<List<SearchModel>> GoAsync(SearchContract search, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {    
            var taskList = new List<Task<List<SearchModel>>>
            {                    
                SearchRoutine1Async(search, cancellationToken),
                SearchRoutine2Async(search, cancellationToken)
            };

            Task<List<SearchModel>> completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(taskList);

            return completedTask.Result;
        }
```

an example of the a task is :

```
public static async Task<List<SearchModel>> SearchRoutine1Async(SearchContract search, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            using (DBContext db = new DBContext)
            {
                var searchModels= await db.SearchModel
                    .Where(sm => sm.subKey1 = search.subKey1)
                    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken)
                    .ConfigureAwait(false)
                    ; 

                return searchModels;
            }
        }
```

The call from the synchronous routine is as follows and it FREEZES on the task.WaitAndUnwrapException...:

```
var task = GoAsync(search);
var result = task.WaitAndUnwrapException();
```

To recap... if i bypass the GoAsync routine and call the tasks individually .. it works doing this from the synchronous routine:

```
var task = SearchRoutine1Async(search);
var result = task.WaitAndUnwrapException();
```

Comment: Don't forget the `.ConfigureAwait(false)` when awaiting `Task.WhenAny`

Comment: @KevinGosse  i think that actually worked.  seems to be at least now.   add to answer and i'll accept.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I was missing .ConfigureAwait(false) after the

```
Task<List<SearchModel>> completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(taskList);
```

to this :

```
Task<List<SearchModel>> completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(taskList).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

@KevinGrosse thanks!

Not sure why i needed it though. Wasn't needed when running in an async pipeline.

Comment: This is a known deadlock condition when waiting synchronously on a task. Just search "deadlock" and "ConfigureAwait", and you'll find plenty of resources explaining what happens

Comment: If you want pipelines use the TPL Dataflow classes like TransformBlock, ActionBlock. It's not trivial to write a pipeline correctly. Or use the System.Threading.Channels classes to communicate between steps.